# PostGIS ST_Intersect - dealing with different coordinate systems

Tags: postgis, st-intersects

I try to get an intersection of two tables - lines and polygons. Lines' CRS is 3006 (SWEREF99 TM), while polygons' CRS is 4326 (WGS84). I write the query:

```sql
SELECT v.subid 
FROM line AS v, polygon AS o
WHERE ST_Intersects(v.geom, ST_Transform(o.geom, 3006));
```

which returns 0 selection while I know that the objects in tables do intersect. What is wrong in the query?

Comment: Your code is working for me

Comment: Are you sure the SRID is assigned correctly on the geometry columns? What happens if you try ST_Transform(o.geom, 4326, 3006) ?   https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html

Comment: It still returns 0 selection. How do I check that srid is assigned correctly?

Comment: you might need to 1st setrid on polygon then st_transform

Comment: Now it says: "ERROR: FEL:  transform: generic error of unknown origin (-61)
SQL state: XX000".

Answer (score 1):

A. Check which coordinate systems (SRID) your tables are in. Don't assume they're in the SRID you think they're in without checking:

```
SELECT ST_SRID(geom) FROM LINE
GROUP BY ST_SRID;
    
SELECT ST_SRID(geom) FROM POLYGON
GROUP BY ST_SRID;
```

Hopefully every geometry in a table is in the same, expected SRID. If SRID isn't set, but you know what the SRID should be, you can do:

```
UPDATE table SET geom = ST_SETSRID(geom,####)
```

B. Check if your geometries are valid in those SRIDS. For 4326 and other geographic SRIDS:

```
SELECT * from POLYGON
WHERE ST_XMAX(geom) > 180 or ST_YMAX(geom) > 90;

UNION

SELECT * FROM POLYGON
WHERE ST_XMIN(geom) < 0 or ST_YMIN(geom) < 0;
```

For projected SRIDs, refer to the bounds listed on the respective epsg.io page. [For 3006](http://epsg.io/3006):

> 181896.33 6101648.07
> 864416.00 7689478.31

If this query returns anything, those records have invalid geometries for their respective SRIDs. I would look at those objects in QGIS and figure out what's going on.

C. With SRIDs determined and geometries validated, you can now run your query:

```
SELECT v.subid 
FROM line AS v, polygon AS o
WHERE ST_Intersects(v.geom, ST_Transform(o.geom, 3006));
```

Comment: I do not quite understand the ST_XMIN etc. tests. In EPSG:4326 value -90, -180 is ok, and projected coordinate systems may have quite large values, both positive and negative.

Comment: That's correct - but every projected SRID has known bounds. Just find them and update the query. Here's the SRID register I use - epsg.io